# Powershell - Supply a collection that does not contain any null values

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script which runs a SQL Server query, exports it to an Excel file, and then is supposed to email that Excel file as an attachment.  The Excel exporter that I'm using is from here: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Here is the script:

```
##--Variables Start
$FileName = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Report.xlsx";
$ConnectionString = "OurConnectionString"
$secpasswd = "emailpassword"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("emailaddress", $secpasswd)
$SmtpCred = $cred
$ToAddress = 'to@contoso.com'
$FromAddress = 'from@contoso.com'
$SmtpServer = 'smtp.server.com'
$SmtpPort = '587'
$Subject = 'Report'
$Body = "Here is your report"

$mailparam = @{
    To = $ToAddress
    From = $FromAddress
    Subject = $Subject
    Body = $Body
    Attachments = $Attachment
    SmtpServer = $SmtpServer
    Port = $SmtpPort
    Credential = $SmtpCred
}

$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.table
"@;

##--Variables End


$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString;

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;


$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];

$xlsFile = @($DataSetTable | Export-Excel $FileName -AutoSize)

$SqlConnection.Close()

$Attachment = $xlsFile

Send-MailMessage @mailparam -UseSsl
```

After running the above script, the Excel file properly exports, but the send mail fails due to an alleged null value in the `$Attachment` variable - I get the following error:

> Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Attachments'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that 
>       does not contain any null values and then try the command again.
>       At C:\Users\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:58 char:18
>       + Send-MailMessage @mailparam -UseSsl
>       +                  ~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingValidationException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

What is wrong with my syntax such that the `$Attachment` variable is empty?

I have another script which is almost identical to this but instead of using  `$xlsFile = @($DataSetTable | Export-Excel $FileName -AutoSize)` for Excel export, it uses an older PowerShell ComObject with a lot more code to do the Excel part - that other script also ends in:

```
$Attachment = $xlsFile

Send-MailMessage @mailparam -UseSsl
```

yet the email with attachment works fine when that one runs.

Comment: In the command `$xlsFile = @($DataSetTable | Export-Excel $FileName -AutoSize)` $xlsfile is empty because Export-Excel doesn't return anything. Use `$Attachment = $FileName`

Comment: @LotPings thanks for the suggestion.  I tried using `$FileName` but received a different error, a `FileNotFound` exception.  `Could not find file 'C:\<the path to the file>'.` That path is the value of the `$FileName` variable.

Comment: In your script above $filename isn't defined. cite from help `Parameter -Attachments <String[]> Specifies the path and file names of files to be attached to the email message. You can use this parameter or pipe the paths and file names to Send-MailMessage`

Comment: It is defined - it's one of the variables that I mention is not included in the script above to save from people having to read irrelevant code.  Of course now it is relevant.  I will edit to include it.

Comment: Post updated to show entire script.

Comment: @Stpete111 - have you carefully reviewed the content of either of the `$xlsFile` or the `$Attachment` variables?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes I have. Do you see something that I’m missing?

Comment: @Stpete111 - no, i was simply covering the diagnostic bases.///// **i just noticed something ... you are defining the splat BEFORE the `$Attachment` variable has anything in it ... [*grin*] move the splat definition to the _standard location_ - just before the call that uses it, and the see if it works correctly.**

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that's the answer!!  Thanks!  Why not move that from the comments to an answer and I'll mark it as the answer?

Comment: @Stpete111 - done! if you have any suggestions on improving it, please let me know. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i *finally* noticed that your splat is defined *before* any value is assigned to $Attachment. [*blush*] that means the splat will NOT have anything in that parameter.

the fix = move the splat to the *standard location* - just before the call that uses it - and therefore *after* the assignment of all the $Vars that it uses. [*grin*]